# Simple result html page with Jersey value

Tags: rest, jersey

Imagine that i have some Jersey method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

What should i do in order to insert %param_value% to huge html page with css and js scripts.

// many html code

// somewhere in the middle

Your param is : %param_value%

// other html code

Comment: What framework are you using to render your HTML? If you're just using HTML you might want to consider JQuery for rendering the result of your REST call.

Comment: @condit could you provide any link about it please?

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989052/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-xml-from-remote-rest-api but instead of just opening a dialog you could use JQuery or JavaScript to populate your HTML content.